# Earliest use of the word 'polytropic' to describe an equation of state or process

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics

When and by whom was the word 'polytropic' first used to describe an equation of state or process of the form $P \propto V^n$? Why was this particular word chosen?

The earliest use of the word that I could find by searching on Google Books was in https://doi.org/10.1080/14786445408647467, which seems to be unrelated to the use I am looking for. The other 'contemporaneous' results I could find seemed to be mostly newer books mislabelled as older ones, or works in which the word was used without any explanation, suggesting it was already well-established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source of word origins and their earliest usages is the Unabridged Oxford English Dictionary. You need a library subscription.

> The first meaning could be of mathematical original since n can assume
>   several values  Mathematics. Of a function: taking several different
>   values for each value of the variable; many-valued. Cf. monotropic
>   adj. 1. Obsolete. rare—0.
>
> **1889   Cent. Dict. at Function   Polydromic or polytropic function, one which is not monotropic.**

Then it defines the usage in thermodynamics and shows a 1907 paper where the authors use this term specifically in thermodynamic sense

> **1907   J. F. Klein tr. G. Zeuner Techn. Thermodynamics I. xxix. 152   If the initial condition is given by p1 and v1, we accordingly have pvn = p1v1n..as the equation of the sought pressure curve, which we will hereafter call the polytropic curve.**

Now you should search the 1907 paper by J. F. Klein.